# docker-compose: previous volume setting overrides changes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've been using a host directory as my data volume for a postgresql container.  My `docker-compose.yml` reads something like this.

```
postgresql:
        image: postgres
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        container_name: postgresql
        networks:
            - mynet
        volumes:
            - pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
    pg-data:
        driver_opts:
            type: none
            device: /volumes/pgdata
            o: bind
```

As we wanted to consolidate all data into a single encrypted volume, I decided to remap the volume for this container.

```
volumes:
    pg-data:
        driver_opts:
            type: none
            device: /volumes/data/pgdata
            o: bind
```

I know that I need to remove the containers of this image and recreate the image.  I removed all containers and images.  It appears that docker-compose is still remembering my old setting somewhere when I try to rebuild (`docker-compose up --build postgresql`) the image.  I get the following error.

```
ERROR: for postgresql  Cannot create container for service postgresql: error while mounting volume with options: type='none' device='/volumes/pgdata' o='bind': no such file or directory
```

Its still trying to access the old volume definition where as my new `docker-compose.yml` has no reference to this directory.

Appreciate some help to resolve this.  Am I missing some steps here?

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be an issue in docker-compose as [per this post](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5772).  This is scheduled to be fixed in the next release.  Meanwhile, the workaround suggested works.

> In the meantime, you should be able to work around the issue by
>   removing the existing volume (either `docker volume rm -f <project>_pg-data`
>   or `docker-compose down -v`)